# Is it possible to integrate existing SOAP endpoints within Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have an existing Spring Boot application (on Tomcat 7) which exposes certain REST endpoints using Spring-MVC and SOAP endpoints using CXF.

I am planning to migrate the application to Spring-Webflux to make the REST endpoints reactive, but have not been able to figure out a way to integrate SOAP endpoints to Spring Webflux ServletHttpHandlerAdapter class.

Does Spring Web Flux provide any way to do such a thing ?